# ASP.NET .ASHX image generation. NotSupportedException

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ashx, notsupportedexception

I am using the following code to draw an image on the fly in my ASP.NET web application.

```
Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim ai As absencestruct = js.Deserialize(Of absencestruct)(CStr(context.Request.QueryString.Item("json")))

    'Ensure font is readable (half height of block or 12px whichever is smaller)
    Dim f As Font = New Font("Calibri", Math.Min(CInt(CDbl(ai.size.height) / 2.5), 12), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

    Dim img As New Bitmap(CInt(ai.size.width), CInt(ai.size.height))
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)

    g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality

    If ai.textStyle <> textStyleEnum.invisible Then
        g.Clear(Color.White)
    End If

    Dim r As New Rectangle(1, 1, CInt(ai.size.width) - 1, CInt(ai.size.height) - 1)

    r = New Rectangle(r.Left + 2, r.Top + 2, r.Width - 4, r.Height - 4)

    drawAbsence(ai, True, r, g)
    If ai.abs2.type <> AbsenceItem.halfDays.Errored AndAlso ai.drawStyle = AbsenceItem.drawStyle.orphan Then
        drawAbsence(ai, False, r, g)
    End If

    Dim s As SizeF = g.MeasureString(ai.day.ToString, f)
    Dim br As SolidBrush = CType(Brushes.Black, SolidBrush)
    If ai.textStyle = textStyleEnum.otherMonth Then br = CType(Brushes.Gray, SolidBrush)

    If ai.textStyle <> textStyleEnum.invisible Then
        g.DrawString(ai.day.ToString, f, br, New Point(CInt((CDbl(ai.size.width) / 2) - CInt(s.Width / 2)), CInt((CDbl(ai.size.height) / 2) - CInt(s.Height / 2))))
    End If

    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png"
    img.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png)
    img.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Previously this worked absolutely fine, however all of a sudden this now errors as soon as it reaches the

```
img.dispose
```

I get an exception NotSupportedException "Specified Method is not supported"

I removed the dispose call to see what happens... at which point I get the exact same error on the

```
End Sub
```

As I believed this to be nearly impossible I have tried both restarting PC and Visual Studio 2012. No effect.

It should be noted that if I skip over the errors the image works perfectly fine, however as I am sure you can appreciate when the page draws anything up to 50 of these images skipping over them can be quite time consuming, on top of this if there is any chance that the image would fail as a result of this I am sure my clients would be less than impressed.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of suggestions:

Rather than calling explicit dispose, you should wrap the use of img and graphics in a Using block.

You should flush and close the response stream to ensure the image is done being used before it is disposed.

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As System.Web.HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim ai As absencestruct = js.Deserialize(Of absencestruct)(CStr(context.Request.QueryString.Item("json")))

    'Ensure font is readable (half height of block or 12px whichever is smaller)
    Dim f As Font = New Font("Calibri", Math.Min(CInt(CDbl(ai.size.height) / 2.5), 12), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

    Using img As New Bitmap(CInt(ai.size.width), CInt(ai.size.height))
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)

            g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality

            If ai.textStyle <> textStyleEnum.invisible Then
                g.Clear(Color.White)
            End If

            Dim r As New Rectangle(1, 1, CInt(ai.size.width) - 1, CInt(ai.size.height) - 1)

            r = New Rectangle(r.Left + 2, r.Top + 2, r.Width - 4, r.Height - 4)

            drawAbsence(ai, True, r, g)
            If ai.abs2.type <> AbsenceItem.halfDays.Errored AndAlso ai.drawStyle = AbsenceItem.drawStyle.orphan Then
                drawAbsence(ai, False, r, g)
            End If

            Dim s As SizeF = g.MeasureString(ai.day.ToString, f)
            Dim br As SolidBrush = CType(Brushes.Black, SolidBrush)
            If ai.textStyle = textStyleEnum.otherMonth Then br = CType(Brushes.Gray, SolidBrush)

            If ai.textStyle <> textStyleEnum.invisible Then
                g.DrawString(ai.day.ToString, f, br, New Point(CInt((CDbl(ai.size.width) / 2) - CInt(s.Width / 2)), CInt((CDbl(ai.size.height) / 2) - CInt(s.Height / 2))))
            End If

            context.Response.ContentType = "image/png"
            img.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png)
            context.Response.Flush()
            context.Response.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, however I know get the exact same message on the context.Reponse.Flush call... Once again if I skip over the message the picture actually renders perfectly fine.

Comment: That's strange. Can you debug and get a stack trace from the exception to see where it originates? That generally helps me narrow down the source of strange problems like this.